# Why does linux audit daemon restart periodically with the following log?

Tags: services, daemon, linux-audit

**Sample Log :**

> type=SERVICE_START msg=audit(1497515461.023:2020433): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg=' comm="systemd-tmpfiles-clean" exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
>
> type=SERVICE_STOP msg=audit(1497515461.023:2020434): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg=' comm="systemd-tmpfiles-clean" exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'

What is so specific to the command `systemd-tmpfiles-clean` that makes it restart audit daemon?